# Blackberry OS 6 Development Environment

Tags: blackberry-jde, blackberry-torch

Will development for the Blackberry Torch (and other selected OS6 blackberries) be done through a new version of the standard RIM JDE or is there a new environment or focus on the Eclipse side of things?

Comment: Any thoughts on this now that a few Blackberry Dev Conferences have passed?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is a new Eclipse plugin that you can download for OS 6 development:
http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/javaappdev/javaupdate.jsp